# How to benchmark init() function

Tags: go

I was playing with following Go code which calculates Population count using lookup table:

```
package population

import (
        "fmt"
)

var pc [256]byte

func init(){
        for i := range pc {
                pc[i] = pc[i/2] + byte(i&1)
        }
}

func countPopulation() {
        var x uint64 = 65535
        populationCount := int(pc[byte(x>>(0*8))] +
                pc[byte(x>>(1*8))] +
                pc[byte(x>>(2*8))] +
                pc[byte(x>>(3*8))] +
                pc[byte(x>>(4*8))] +
                pc[byte(x>>(5*8))] +
                pc[byte(x>>(6*8))] +
                pc[byte(x>>(7*8))])

        fmt.Printf("Population count: %d\n", populationCount)
}
```

I have written following benchmark code to check performance of above code block:

```
package population

import "testing"

func BenchmarkCountPopulation(b *testing.B) {
        for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
                countPopulation()
        }
}
```

Which gave me following result:

```
100000             18760 ns/op
PASS
ok      gopl.io/ch2     2.055s
```

Then I moved the code from `init()` function to the `countPopulation()` function as below:

```
func countPopulation() {
        var pc [256]byte

        for i := range pc {
                pc[i] = pc[i/2] + byte(i&1)
        }

        var x uint64 = 65535
        populationCount := int(pc[byte(x>>(0*8))] +
                pc[byte(x>>(1*8))] +
                pc[byte(x>>(2*8))] +
                pc[byte(x>>(3*8))] +
                pc[byte(x>>(4*8))] +
                pc[byte(x>>(5*8))] +
                pc[byte(x>>(6*8))] +
                pc[byte(x>>(7*8))])

        fmt.Printf("Population count: %d\n", populationCount)
}
```

and once again ran the same benchmark code, which gave me following result:

```
100000             20565 ns/op
PASS
ok      gopl.io/ch2     2.303s
```

After observing both the results it is clear that `init()` function is not in the scope of benchmark function. That's why first benchmark execution took lesser time compared to second execution.

Now I have another question which I am looking to get answer for.

**If I need to benchmark only the `init()` method, considering there can be multiple `init()` functions in a package. How is it done in `golang`?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "If I need to benchmark only the init() method". No you don't. And you cannot. And you should not. init functions are a way of doing one-time setup work. One-time work _cannot_ be benchmarked reliably. If you have two different ways of doing this work: Write two functions, benchmark them and call the faster one in init. Done. Trying to benchmark init by itself is _wrong_.

Comment: You worry about a function that runs exactly once and takes a few microseconds? Really? Then you have to move your code into a new function, call it from init, and benchmark that new function.

Answer (score 4):

Yes there can be multiple `init()`'s in a package, in-fact you can have multiple `init()`'s in a file. More information about init can be found [here](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#init). Remember that `init()` is automatically called one time before your program's `main()` is even started.

The benchmark framework runs your code multiple times (in your case 100000). This allows it to measure very short functions, as well as very long functions. It doesn't make sense for benchmark to include the time for `init()`. The problem you are having is that you are not understanding the purpose of benchmarking. Benchmarking lets you compare two or more separate implementations to determine which one is faster (also you can compare performance based on input of the same function). It does not tell you where you should be doing that.

What you are basically doing is known as [Premature Optimization](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization). It's where you start optimizing code trying to make it as fast as possible, without knowing where your program actually spends most of its time. [Profiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) is the process of measuring the time and space complexity of a program. In practice, it allows you to see where your program is spending most of its time. Using that information, you can write more efficient functions. More information about profiling in go can be found in this [blog post](https://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs).